# Replace Host URL including square brackets

Tags: regex, sed

In Ubuntu 18.04 I am trying to replace a line `hosts: ["localhost:9200"]` with `hosts:"http:xx.xx.xx:9200"` by using the below command but it's not getting updated in the target file.

```
sed -i  's/hosts: ["localhost:9200"]/hosts:"http:xx.xx.xx:9200"/g' /home/test/beat.yaml
```

What is the problem? How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

In a regular expression `[` and `]` embrace a character set. `[something]` matches either character from the set `s`, `o`, `m`, `e`, `t`, `h`, `i`, `n`, `g`.

Your command would replace e.g. `hosts: 9` because `9` is in the set you (inadvertently) defined.

You want to match literal `[` and `]` characters. For this you need to escape at least `[`, although there's nothing wrong in escaping both. You escape a character with `\`. Try this:

```
sed 's/hosts: \["localhost:9200"]/hosts:"http:xx.xx.xx:9200"/g' /home/test/beat.yaml
```

Note I omitted `-i`. I guess you should de-obfuscate `xx.xx.xx`, examine if the output is right, add `-i` only if it is.

If you want to "replace a line `hosts: ["localhost:9200"]`" strictly, i.e. only where the pattern forms a full line (as opposed to a part of a line), then you should use anchors that match the beginning and the end of the line. These are `^` and `$` respectively. `g` is not needed then.

```
sed 's/^hosts: \["localhost:9200"]$/hosts:"http:xx.xx.xx:9200"/' /home/test/beat.yaml
```

Keep in mind any additional space (or tab, or anything) in an otherwise matching line will make the line not match. The space(s) may be stray or deliberate (e.g. for indentation). Ask yourself if you really need these anchors.

Comment: Its works, thanks